# Expression result unused warning in for loop

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I am getting "Expression result unused" warning in the following for loop.

```
   NSInteger i = 0;
   for ( i; i < tags.count; i ++) {

   }
```

Seems like I am missing some basic knowledge on how the for loops works , Can anyone shed some light on reason for this warning ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you declared `i` outside the loop, the expression `i` in the first part of the `for` is unused:

```
for ( i /* <<== This one */ ; i < tags.count; i ++) {

}
```

The syntax of the `for` loop lets you drop the content of any of its three expression compartments. This should fix the problem:

```
for ( ; i < tags.count; i ++) {

}
```

In fact, you can drop all three, making the loop infinite:

```
for ( ; ; ) {
    ...
    if (some_condition) break;
    ...
}
```

Note: in general, you should declare loop variables as part of the loop header. The only exception is when you need to use the final value of `i` outside your loop.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with:

```
for ( NSInteger i = 0; i < tags.count; i ++) {

}
```